# How to set date with hrs and minutes greater than given date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write an inquiry which returns all records where date with hrs and minutes is greater than 5:30. Example: we have dates: 2018-10-18 03:00 and 2018-10-18 05:40. I need to return only the second one. What I'm doing now is (in 'select' part):

```
case
when DATEPART(hh,Table1.CreateDate)>05 and DATEPART(mi,Table1.CreateDate)>30 then 'late_status' end as Statuses
```

The problem is that I need to have those 2 terms fulfilled at the same time. I also used brackets but it is still not correct. Basically, it doesn't work well, where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using times directly?

```
where cast(Table1.CreateDate as time) >= '05:30:00'
```

Comment: @Muska Great - can you please start marking the answers as such? That is how SO is designed to work. People have questions, look on SO for answers. Marking the answer helps others find it.

Comment: Yes, I marked it as useful, something else? Sorry Im quite a newbie to the site

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if you can, (and you need to base queries on the time a lot) I would add a `time` version of your `datetime` column as a `PERSISTED` computed column and query that. That maintains SARGability.

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD CreateTime AS CONVERT(time, CreateDate);
```

Then you can query your new column:

```
WHERE CreateTime >= '05:30:00'
```

You can also then add the computed column to any indexes, or create ones on or including it.

Answer (score 0):

It will be `MINUTE` instead `mi` and your query also work

```
case
    when DATEPART(hh,Table1.CreateDate)=05 and DATEPART(MINUTE,Table1.CreateDate)>=30 then 'late_status' end as Statuses
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=797a851a328d377074e12689155deae8)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk please check this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0bcdc2b935319d0b764a2213a1d140a0 and have a look it works fine

Comment: Your code fails on my example and on the data provided in the question. It should be DATEPART(hh,Table1.CreateDate)=5 and DATEPART(MINUTE,Table1.CreateDate)>30 or 
DATEPART(hh,Table1.CreateDate)>5  if you want to go by your solution

Comment: @t-clausen.dk aggred for exact 5.30  with you,actually i focused main problem of OP's cause he missed  to get minute and edited the condition btw thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks but I'm curious about one thing, why mi can't be used in taht case but full-lenght word minute? Look here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datepart.asp. Theoretically I can use Minute, mi and n for minutes in Datepart.